# Django change Models relations depending on condition (if is staff or not)

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 Moles, User and Account. The User can be staff or normal User.
In general a User can have just one Account.

This is what I have now:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but in special cases an User can have multiple or no Account, only if the User is_staff.

The logic is to have now a ForeignKey:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But in this case, how do I stop in Django Admin or else, for a User to have multiple Foreign keys if is not staff, and force it for normal users to have a simulated OneToOne Relation.

Comment: Why don't you handle this validation in `User.save()`? There you know if the the user `is_staff=True` and you can raise `ValidationError` if it doesn't match your rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a [Many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relation where one staff User can have multiple accounts, is your Account model that should contain your foreign key. Also, you can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) your Account's save model to reinforce your condition using a code similar to this:

```
class Account(...):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.user
        if user and user.set_account.count() > 0 and not user.is_staff:
            raise ValidationError(_('You cannot add another account to user {}'.format(user.username)))
        super(Account, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```